# HTML Space missing

Tags: html, css, spacing

So I'm making HTML boxes on my website. But the problem is the box is not where I want it to be and it runs out of room on the page. How do I fix this?

```css
div.relative {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background: #262626;
   color: #EEEEEE;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
   body {
      padding: 500px 0 0 0;
      width: 100%
   }
}

a {
   color: inherit;
}

.menu-item,
.menu-open-button {
   background: #EEEEEE;
   border-radius: 100%;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   margin-left: -40px;
   position: absolute;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 80px;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
   transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
   transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
   transition: transform ease-out 200ms, -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
}

.menu-open {
   display: none;
}

.lines {
   width: 25px;
   height: 3px;
   background: #596778;
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -12.5px;
   margin-top: -1.5px;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
   transition: -webkit-transform 200ms;
   transition: transform 200ms;
   transition: transform 200ms, -webkit-transform 200ms;
}

.line-1 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, -8px, 0);
}

.line-2 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.line-3 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 8px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-1 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-2 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(0.1, 1);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button .line-3 {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu {
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   text-align: center;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 26px;
}


/* .menu-item {
   transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
} */

.menu-item:hover {
   background: #EEEEEE;
   color: #3290B1;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(8) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-item:nth-child(9) {
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   transition-duration: 180ms;
}

.menu-open-button {
   z-index: 2;
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
   transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
   -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
   transition-duration: 400ms;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   cursor: pointer;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: scale(1.2, 1.2) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button {
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
   transition-timing-function: linear;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
   transition-duration: 200ms;
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item {
   -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
   transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
   transition-duration: 180ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0.08361px, -104.99997px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
   transition-duration: 280ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 280ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(90.9466px, -52.47586px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
   transition-duration: 380ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 380ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(90.9466px, 52.47586px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
   transition-duration: 480ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 480ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0.08361px, 104.99997px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(7) {
   transition-duration: 580ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 580ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-90.86291px, 52.62064px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(8) {
   transition-duration: 680ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 680ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-91.03006px, -52.33095px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(9) {
   transition-duration: 780ms;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 780ms;
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
   transform: translate3d(-0.25084px, -104.9997px, 0);
}

.blue {
   background-color: #669AE1;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.blue:hover {
   color: #669AE1;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.green {
   background-color: #70CC72;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.green:hover {
   color: #70CC72;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.red {
   background-color: #FE4365;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.red:hover {
   color: #FE4365;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.purple {
   background-color: #C49CDE;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.purple:hover {
   color: #C49CDE;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.orange {
   background-color: #FC913A;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.orange:hover {
   color: #FC913A;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.lightblue {
   background-color: #62C2E4;
   box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.lightblue:hover {
   color: #62C2E4;
   text-shadow: none;
}

.credit {
   margin: 24px 20px 120px 0;
   text-align: right;
   color: #EEEEEE;
}

.credit a {
   padding: 8px 0;
   color: #C49CDE;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.credit a:hover {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div>
<nav class="menu">
   <input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open" id="menu-open" />
   <label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open">
    <span class="lines line-1"></span>
    <span class="lines line-2"></span>
    <span class="lines line-3"></span>
  </label>

   <a href="#" class="menu-item blue"> <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item green"> <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item red"> <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item purple"> <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item orange"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i> </a>
   <a href="#" class="menu-item lightblue"> <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> </a>
</nav>
</div>
```

That's my code but this is what happens
bronmc.enjin.com/classes
How would I fix this? I am pretty sucky at HTML and CSS. I found this code online, I know enough to edit it how I like it. How would I position it below the search bar and make the page big enough to fit the whole menu?

Comment: Where's the search bar in the example? If you know the height of the search bar, and the height of other elements before it, you should be able to position the menu below the search bar by setting the `top` of the menu position to below the search bar.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is im using a website builder called enjin and they dont just have a raw HTML editor, you have to create HTML modules and then place them in the spaces given on the website creator